# Return multiple values from an Oracle function

Tags: oracle, function

I need to return several varchar variables from an Oracle function but when it returns something the function exits immediately. Is there any way I can do this?

Here I return the first value that matches the condition but I want to return all of them.

```
create or replace function f_pilotosContinentes return varchar as

cursor cc(codigoPiloto int) is
    select count(*) as numero from(
        select distinct pi.codigo, c.nome from Voo v
        join Rota r on r.codigo = v.rota
        join Aeroporto a on a.codigo = r.localDestino
        join Pais p on p.codigo = a.pais
        join Continente c on c.codigo = p.continente
        join PilotoVoo pv on pv.voo = v.codigo
        join Piloto pi on pi.codigo = pv.piloto
        where pi.codigo = codigoPiloto);
pilotos cc%rowtype;

cursor cc1 is
    select p.codigo from Piloto p;
codPilotos cc1%rowtype;

duracao int;
temp int;
piloto varchar(20);

begin

duracao := 0;

open cc1;
    loop
        fetch cc1 into codPilotos;
        exit when cc1%notfound;
        --Verificar para cada piloto
        open cc(codPilotos.codigo);
            loop
                fetch cc into pilotos;
                exit when cc%notfound;

                if pilotos.numero between 3 and 4 then
                    --Buscar a duração total dos voos dele
                    select sum(v.duracao) into temp from Voo v
                    join PilotoVoo pv on pv.voo = v.codigo
                    join Piloto p on p.codigo = pv.piloto
                    where p.codigo = codPilotos.codigo;

                    if temp > duracao or duracao = 0 then
                        duracao := temp;
                    end if;
                end if;

            end loop;
        close cc;               
    end loop;
close cc1;

open cc1;
    loop
        fetch cc1 into codPilotos;
        exit when cc1%notfound;
        --Verificar para cada piloto
        open cc(codPilotos.codigo);
            loop
                fetch cc into pilotos;
                exit when cc%notfound;

                if pilotos.numero >= 3 then
                    --Buscar a duração total dos voos dele
                    select sum(v.duracao) into temp from Voo v
                    join PilotoVoo pv on pv.voo = v.codigo
                    join Piloto p on p.codigo = pv.piloto
                    where p.codigo = codPilotos.codigo;

                    if temp = duracao then
                        select p.nome into piloto from Piloto p
                        where p.codigo = codPilotos.codigo;
                        return piloto;
                    end if;
                end if;

            end loop;
        close cc;               
    end loop;
close cc1;

dbms_output.put_line('Nenhum piloto viajou para todos os continentes.');
return null;

end;
```

Comment: Please post what code you have so far, it will help us asses your needs.

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do here. The RETURN statement is documented to exit either a function or a procedure when it is reached (this is not uncommon among programming languages!) There's no indication here what you are trying to return or where. It's certainly possible to return multiple values by returning an array, nested table etc but if we don't know what you're trying to do I don't see how you can expect much help...

Comment: I can just guess from you having a single assignment in a loop. Maybe you want to return a value per loop execution. Have a look at [Oracle Pipelined Table Functions](http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_pipe_functions.html)?

Comment: After this, I open again the cursor to see which rows match the variable "duracao" and then return it. The thing is not only one row will match that variable? Am I being clear ?

Comment: So you have a single cursor into which you pass a value. You're looping through that cursor and returning the first value but want to return every value? How are you using these values? Are you able to post the relevant code rather than this, which doesn't seem to be...

Comment: Hi I'm sorry you felt aggrieved but there was really no reason to be. If you look back at your first few revisions of this post you really did post the wrong half. I'm sorry if I've offended. Your code mentions a cursor, `cc` for which there is no code and it really would be helpful to know how you are using the returned values.

Comment: There we go. I wasn't being able to post all code since StackOverflow was telling me there was too much code on the question. Sorry for the wasted time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways you can return multiple strings from a PL/SQL method:

1. Populate and return a VARCHAR2 array instead of a single VARCHAR2
2. Use a procedure instead with multiple OUT parameters (suitable if there are a fixed number of return values you want to return, especially if they have different meanings - e.g. name, address, state, etc.)
3. Use a view instead. This would require transforming the procedural logic from your function into SQL predicates.

Side note: if the function is changed to return an array, you can then if you wish change it to a pipelined function, which would mean that if you call it from a SQL query, it will begin consuming rows as soon as the function returns them, instead of waiting for the function to finish. This may help with performance (both speed and memory usage).

Comment: Could you please show me an example of how to return a varchar2 array ?

Comment: You declare an array type, and return that type from your function like any other data type. http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/appdev.111/b28370/collections.htm#CJABADDJ